# including somedialog.h into other parts of the project makes ui_somedialog.h invisible to compiler

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, shared-libraries, qmake

I'm trying to use a custom Qt Dialog differently in a project. There are two scenarios, where the same problem occurs.

**1. I'm including the dialog into the main project as a library.**
The library is part of a bigger subdirs project, which also contains the main app that will use it. Here's the project tree:

```
AppProject
|_AppProject.pro
|_MyApp
  |_myapp.pro
  |_main.cpp
  |_mainwindow.h
  |_mainwindow.cpp
  |_mainwindow.ui
|_GUILib
  |_guilib.pro
  |_guilib_decl.h
  |_somedialog.h
  |_somedialog.cpp
  |_somedialog.ui
```

Source files here:

> [main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/9n3dKy2p)   [mainwindow.h](https://pastebin.com/WQvDscym)   [mainwindow.cpp](https://pastebin.com/P6YuAUk0)
>   [guilib_decl.h](https://pastebin.com/FZcEr0wb)   [somedialog.h](https://pastebin.com/qLSE5ZZf)   [somedialog.cpp](https://pastebin.com/tZUMtptB)
>   [somedialog.ui](https://pastebin.com/qvTmMGby)

The AppProject is a normal subdirs project, that includes both MyApp and GUILib:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += MyApp \
           GUILib

MyApp.depends = GUILib
```

MyApp is a normal app template:

```
QT += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += c++14

DEPENDPATH += ../GUILib

INCLUDEPATH += ../GUILib

LIBS += -L../GUILib -lGUILib  

HEADERS += mainwindow.h \

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           mainwindow.cpp \

FORMS +=   mainwindow.ui \
```

And here's the lib project file:

```
QT += core widgets gui

TARGET = GUILib
TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG -= debug_and_release

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += GUILIB_LIBRARY


HEADERS += \
    guilib_decl.h \
    somedialog.h

SOURCES += \
    guilib.cpp \
    somedialog.cpp

FORMS += \
    somedialog.ui
```

The library can be built on its own (no problems, ui_somedialog.h is found), but if I include somedialog.h into mainwindow.h, then the compiler spits the following error message:

> ui_somedialog.h: No such file or directory

**2. I'm including the dialog into a test as a non-library.**

Here the project tree looks like this:

```
AppProject
    |_AppProject.pro
    |_MyApp
      |_myapp.pro
      |_main.cpp
      |_mainwindow.h
      |_mainwindow.cpp
      |_mainwindow.ui
      |_somedialog.h
      |_somedialog.cpp
      |_somedialog.ui
    |_Tests
      |_tests.pro
      |_main.cpp
      |_tst_somedialog.cpp
```

It is still a subdirs project, but this time one of them is a Test project, and the dialog is just a normal part (non-lib) of the app.

The project file for the tests look like this:

```
QT += testlib
QT += widgets gui

TARGET = Tests
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += testcase 
CONFIG -= debug_and_release

INCLUDEPATH += ../MyApp

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    tst_somedialog.cpp \
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to matter if the dialog is a lib or not, the same error message is shown by the compiler in both cases. The most interesting part is, that the ui file is where it is supposed to be (uic did its job), so theoretically the compiler should find it in both cases, but for some reason it doesn't. Is there some secret I'm not aware of to make it work? Why is ui_somedialog.h invisible to the compiler when I try to use it somewhere else?

Thanks.

EDIT: modified to include scenario 2.

EDIT2: added source files for scenario 1.

Comment: Library with Dialog ? is this a good approach ..?

Comment: It is just a concept. To be honest, the same problem occurred while I was trying to use the dialog in a unit test. The ui_somedialog.h was found if it wasn't used in the test, but on the other hand if it was included into the test, the same problem occurred. I thought if I make the to be tested dialog a library (and all the other gui elements), the problem could be solved, but apparently not. These problems seem to be related somehow. I think if I find a solution to this, the test problem could also be solved the same way.

Comment: We need to see the code in somedialog.cpp and .h to be able to say what the problem really is.

Comment: Added code sample for scenario one. It will generate the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: @pusrob i already gave you an answer, don't inherit from the generated code, use the approach that i presented there (the private member pointer). That way you don't expose your library "internals" and you reduce the number of headers that you export for your library.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to keep all the gui in the main application, but since this is not always an option, read further.

First i want to mention the reason why that happens, so that is because the `GUILib/GeneratedFiles` (or whatever the path where Qt tools are configured to put the files generated by `uic`) is not in the `INCLUDEPATH` of MyApp, a quick hack would be to add that path to `INCLUDEPATH`, but that will further complicate stuff like if you want to deploy your library, you'll need to make sure that the tools are configured to create the files in the same path on all platforms, so not recommended solution.

A much better solution is to create a class that wraps the dialog using [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), and basically from all the external sources you only include the header/s that contain the PIMPL "interface".

NOTE: With `QObject` the parent is responsible to delete it's children, so to avoid double-delete don't use `std::unique_ptr` in case you set a parent to your dialog.

LE:
Or a 3'rd option (actually this is just PIMPL, so technically it's still second option) would be to avoid the include of the generated file (ui_somedialog.h) into the somedialog.h (the header that you include where you use your library), see the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-single-inheritance-approach) on how you can use the uic generated code into C++ code (look at `Using a Pointer Member Variable`).

*//somedialog.h*

```
#include <QWidget>
//notice there is no include for ui_somedialog.h
namespace Ui {
// forward reference for the generated class
    class SomeDialog;
}

class SomeDialog : public QWidget
~SomeDialog();
//...
private:
//member pointer to the generated class
    Ui::SomeDialog* ui;
}
```

*//somedialog.cpp*

```
#include "somedialog.h"
//here we have the include for ui_somedialog.h
#include "ui_somedialog.h"

SomeDialog::SomeDialog(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::SomeDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SomeDialog::~SomeDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

This is a PIMPL-like approach, you only forward-reference the internal class and export an interface to it.

There was a way to set which approach you wanted Qt tools to generate the code for you, but i can't find it right now, for me the current tools always seem to use this member pointer approach.

Comment: So we should forget libraries and put everything in one blob. That's how things were done in the 1980's. Then you're talking about PIMPL while he never asked about anything related. And the use of std::unique_ptr is totally out of the scope of the question too. Basically, your answer tells nothing and his problem is unsolved. Furthermore, his INCLUDEPATH is set correctly.

Comment: @fonZ i have a few points in my defence: 1) we should use libraries, but i still think it's a good design idea to keep the gui in one place, not scattered across all libraries 2) this INCLUDEPATH is set correctly if he doesn't export generated code 3) PIMPL is a pretty good approach for when you want to keep internals from "leaking" from a library 4) unique_ptr is used in the link with pimpl example, i just reminded him that QObject has it's own way for managing memory and it can interfere with smart pointers.

Comment: 1) You should always strive to write code that is modular. The best example is Qt itself. 2) If you compile a library, then the generated code is included. If it's not, then it's generated by the application that uses it. 3) Qt has it's own PIMPL idiom. 4) Qt uses raw pointers, using std::unique_ptr will most probably break stuff because Qt was never built for that, and you will have to convert your smart pointers everywhere. Second of all, Qt uses a parent child approach to manage memory, delete the parent and the children will also be deleted. You look at Qt as if it was just plain C++.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer, that's why I downvoted it. And let me rephrase as I feel this becomes a game of words. 1)No you said put it all together. 2) I said OR and there is absolutely nothing wrong with including generated code in your library to avoid to have to regenerate every time. 3)Qt has its own implementation of the PIMPL idiom, so blindly using idioms in Qt is wrong when you don't know how to use it. 4)Your example is wrong. The bottom line is that the question stays unanswered and that this discussion is pointless talking about subjects that are not relevant.